# SSIS Package Upgrade Issues 2008 to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade SSIS packages created in SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016 by opening the solution in Visual studio 2015 in my local. I'm using the correct version of SSDT for VS 2015. I have selected all the SSIS packages in the solution for upgrade and upgrade was unsuccessful with the below error messages.

I tried to open the packages in the solution one by one and it shown the dialogue upgrade is successful with some warnings. Please help me to solve the issues shown in the below error messages. As I have upgraded the package individually by opening it, will there be any other issues? (I can run it in local and still didn't try to put the package in our system where packages are getting called automatically)

Main error messages:

Upgrading package XXXX.dtsx (Error)

Messages

- Warning 0x4020f42c: : The Maximum insert commit size property of the OLE DB destination "OLE DB Destination" is set to 0. This property setting can cause the running package to stop responding. For more information, see the F1 Help topic for OLE DB Destination Editor (Connection Manager Page).
- Error 0xc0202009: XXXX: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.".
- Error 0xc020801c: Load new records: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "YYYYYY" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Comment: The first one isn't an error but a warning, and there's no pressing reason to do anything about it. If the package worked with that before, it should continue to work now. The other two methods mean exactly what they say on the tin: SSIS can't open the connections from your local machine, so it can't verify correctness of things like metadata. Again, assuming the package worked before that should pose no issues. For reasons too obvious to mention, you should find a way to test things in a representative staging environment. Use a backup on live if necessary.

Comment: What have you done to investigate these errors?   There's no way someone who doesn't have access to your code and network can help with the information you have provided.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, it seems to be working now when I placed packages in the place where it is getting called